# Aurelia - Watch Dependency Value for Change

Tags: aurelia

Suppose you have a class you are injecting into a another class or component. Is there a way to watch for changes on an attributed of the dependency you are injecting and act upon it?

For example, say you have the following app:

app.html

```
<template>
  <input type="text" value.bind="item">
  <button click.trigger="addToList()">Add</button>

  <h3>Modded</h3>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="it of modded">${it}</li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Original</h3>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="it of dep.items">${it}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

app.js

```
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Dep} from './dep';

@inject(Dep)
export class App {
  constructor(dep) {
    this.dep = dep;
  }

  attached() {
    this.modifyItems();
  }

  addToList() {
    this.dep.addItem(this.item);
  }

  modifyItems() {
    this.modded = [];
    for (let item of this.dep.items) {
      this.modded.push(item.toUpperCase());
    }
  }
}
```

dep.js

```
export class Dep {
  constructor() {
    this.items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  }

  addItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }
}
```

Now, let's say that some other component modifies Dep.items. Is there a way to watch for changes in `app.js` on `this.dep.items` and then call `modifyItems()`?

Assume `modifyItems()` is more complex than this example so maybe a value converter is not the best option. (unless it is the only option I guess)

Here is working plunker with the above example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rEs9UM?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone pointed me to the `BindingEngine.collectionObserver` and it appears that is what I needed.

app.js:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding';
import {Dep} from './dep';

@inject(Dep, BindingEngine)
export class App {
  constructor(dep, bindingEngine) {
    this.dep = dep;

    let subscription = bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.dep.items)
      .subscribe((newVal, oldVal) => {
        console.debug(newVal, oldVal);
        this.modifyItems();
      });
  }

  attached() {
    this.modifyItems();
  }

  addToList() {
    this.dep.addItem(this.item);
    this.item = '';
  }

  modifyItems() {
    this.modded = [];
    for (let item of this.dep.items) {
      this.modded.push(item.toUpperCase());
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the working pluker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pcyxrh?p=preview